# Disable in-app payments on android

Tags: android, billing, in-app

I'm trying to create an easier library to manage in-app payments in Android.

I'm dealing now with the CHECK_BILLING_SUPPORTED method to test if in-app payments are enabled or not, but I can't find a way to disable these payments, and this method always returns true in a Spanish Samsung Galaxy Tab.

I have read something about parental control option, but it doesn't exist in my tablet. Has anybody else had the same problem and knows how to disable these payments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable this system-wide, it is controlled by the Play Store app. Any parental control/PIN settings are there. To disable in your app, just don't let people press the 'Buy' button without entering the password/PIN/whatever.